# Me sale la IP a null DJANGO

Tags: django

Hola tengo intencion de que cada vez que un usuario complete el formulario me aparezca su IP, pero me aparece a null. Le paso un get client ip y que me devuelva la Ip pero me sigue saliendo null y en el modelo lo tengo definido como:

```
ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(blank=True, null=True)

class fichador_view_entrada(CreateViewEntrada):
    model = fichador
    fields = ['Codigo']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.tipo = "Entrada"
        return super(fichador_view_entrada, self).form_valid(form)
    
    def get_client_ip(request):
        x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
        if x_forwarded_for:
            ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        return ip

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['entrada'] = fichador.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: Asignas a `ip` pero retornas `IP`. Algo tendrá que ver...

Comment: Que debo retornar?

Comment: Pues `ip`, ¿no?

Comment: Si, pero no funciona eso ya lo cambie, Quiero pasar la ip que me saca ahi a bd, cuando le doy al formulario me sale null, como que no se esta enviando

Comment: Posiblemente sea cosa del formulario, creo que hay que incluir la forma en la que intentas usar el dato que retorna ese método. Has intentado hacer debug y ver si retorna algún valor?

Comment: No me retorna nada, necesito incluirlo en la funcion  del form_valid pero no sé como porque no paso el request